# Animate a movement of a UIImageView from start point to end point

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview, xcode6

I have a game where I have an object (UIImageView = redBar) that I want to move from its start point to a given point (in this case, go down diagonally 30 and back 30 again), once the scene is loaded up.
What I am doing is:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {self.redBar.center = CGPointMake(self.redBar.center.x + 30, self.redBar.center.y + 30)}, completion: {(value: Bool) in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {self.redBar.center = CGPointMake(self.redBar.center.x - 30, self.redBar.center.y - 30)}, completion: nil)})
```

What happens is, I put my redBar UIImageView on my storyboard, and when I load up that scene, it's as if my redBar image teleports up and then it starts animating.. Is this the best way to animate an image movement? I really need help on this...

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be with a CGAffineTransform. Just put

```
self.redbar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(30, 30)
```

Inside your animateWithDuration block, and then use -30 for the way back (form is (x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) )

Make sure that the UIImageView is either instantiated from a storyboard or added in viewDidLoad().  If added in code, it would be safest to set its frame in viewWillLayoutSubviews().

Let me know if you need more code to go off of.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That seems to give me the same error... Is it because I'm using constraints? I added my redBar on my StoryBoard, added some suggested constraints, and when I load the app, it seems as if the redBar just teleports and THEN it does its animation!

Comment: In that case you should be animating the constraints. Drag an instance of the constraints into the class and then in animateWithDuration set what you want each constraint to be and then call self.view.layoutIfNeeded() (still inside the block)

Comment: When you say teleport is this before the animation? Does it teleport if you comment out the aninationWithDuration block?

Comment: Oh ok! Didn't know I could work with the constraints, that sounds complicated... :(

Comment: If I do remove the animateWithDuration it just stays there as normal!

Comment: What should I make happen to the constraints? I only have two, which are the ones that center to the X and to the Y

Comment: Just what you were doing in code in your question, except use myConstraint.constant += 30

Comment: You can control-drag the constraint into code just like you would any other object, it's actually really simple

Comment: Ok can you help me out a bit more? My object is in the lower right part of the screen. So I dragged the xconstraint and the yconstraint to my ViewController class. On the animation, I did the CGAffineTransform thing you told me to do, with (150, 150), and then I did xconstraint.constant += 150 and the same for yconstraint. It doesn't show up on the screen and no movement is made.. Help please

Comment: Ditch the CGAffineTransorm, I didn't realize you were using auto layout. Stick the constraint change in the animate with duration block. Are you constraining the distance to the lower and right sides of the screen?